# SQL Find the average of 3 day closest

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL structure like this:

```
Create Table Transactions (
Id integer primary key not null auto_increment,
ResourceId varchar(255),
Price Integer,
TransactionTime date
);
```

I would like to get the time (TransactionTime) along with the average of 3 days price. For example, the 3 day average of the 22nd will be the average of the 20th, 21st, and 22nd.
Thanks so much.

Comment: *For example, the 3 day average of the 22nd will be the average of the 20th, 21st, and 22nd.* This looks not like "closest" but like "closest but not above". Clarify please.

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: Hi @Akina, It means the average of the 20th will be the average price from 22nd to 20th.

Comment: Why not from 19th till 21th?

Comment: `TransactionTime` is not defined as unique, so you may have duplicates by this column... what do you need to obtain when such duplicates are present?

Comment: We will group by TransactionTime. And why not from 19th till 21th because this is the requirement.

Comment: You should formulate all the requirements and rules yourself, and not wait for us to guess what they are.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Hi @Akina, thanks so much for your response, I already assumed that because the TransactionTime will be selected as the key for the average price, so we must group by TransactionTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want this information on each row and for a given resource.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       avg(price) over (partition by resourceid
                        order by transactiontime
                        range between interval 2 day preceding and current row
                       ) as avg_3
from transactions t;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL server:

```
SELECT AVG(Price), MAX(TransactionTime) FROM Transactions GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), TransactionTime) / 3);
```

Comment: Mysql does not have getdate function

Comment: @P.Salmon Use CURDATE() then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested select:

```
select t.TransactionTime,
    (select sum(t1.Price) / 3
    from Transactions t1 where t1.Data in (t.Data, t.Date-2);) as avg3;
   
from Transactions t;
```

[image: demo]